# android studio lambda expressions are not supported at language level 7

Tags: lambda, showdialog

I am getting the error lamba expressions are not supported at language level 7 in android studio that i am using. Anyone know how i could fix this issue.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
            showDialog();
            //Intent cartIntent = new Intent(Home.this, Cart.class);
            //startActivity(cartIntent);
    });
```